# Resolving conflicts w.r.t ambiguous names during imports in rust

Tags: rust, rust-polars

New to rust and was trying to develop an application in rust, but ran into an issue.

In my application, i have to use `zip` module for unzipping a `.zip` file and need `polars` for analysis.

my imports looks like something below.

```
use zip::ZipArchive;
use polars::prelude::*;

.
.
```

but unfortunately `rust-analyzer` is complaining with the following message.

```
unresolved import `zip::ZipArchive`
no `ZipArchive` in `chunked_array::ops::zip
```

I tried the following too with no luck.

```
use zip::ZipArchive;
use polars::prelude::*;
use polars::chunked_array::ops::{zip as chunked_zip};
.
.
```

In my code, i am not explicitly using `chunked_array::ops::zip`, but would like to understand how to solve in both cases.

1. Do not explicitly use `chunked_array::ops::zip`
2. explicitly use `chunked_array::ops::zip`

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why glob imports are usually frowned upon, especially if the module you import from has popular names like `zip`.

You can either import from `zip` with an absolute path `use ::zip::ZipArchive`<sup>1</sup>,

explicitly import the things you need yourself and remove the `use polars::prelude::*;`

Or rename the `zip` crate for example in your `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[dependencies]
zip_renamed = { package = "zip", … }
```

---

<sup>1) Thanks Sven Marnach</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure wildcard imports from a prelude are frowned upon. The whole point of preludes is to wildcard import from it, and even the standard library contains preludes.

Comment: Thanks cafce25 and Sven. Although i'll go with the first approach suggested here, i,e explicitly import the required modules/structs, the second approach was the answer i was looking at, in case if i hit into something in the future.

Comment: @SvenMarnach The *language prelude* is in a unique position: everyone knows it, _and_ name resolution de-prioritizes it relative to all other imports. Both of these factors make it less problematic than glob imports (whether or not someone calls the module imported from "`prelude`").

Comment: @KevinReid I was mostly referring to modules like `std::io::prelude` or `std::simd::prelude`, which don't have any of these special properties. They exclusively exist to be wildcard-imported.